# How to show GUI of browser test case running on some server in the client browser

Tags: python, selenium

In my project we are running test case on worker nodes but currently I am using headless browser to run those test case. But now I want to have a way so that I can show them the test case running in client browser itself only.

I search for selenium grid and other ways like VNC but still not sure how to integrate it all so that when a test executes on a server(ubuntu), user should able to see it.

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi Moshe, Thanks for replying.
But actually I have already implemented using headless and the other option using Xrdp by setting up display value. But the problem is in headless I can't show my user what is exactly happening and using xrdp I can't ask my user to connect to the system.
As I was thinking of a way, so that we show the test running in browser and whatever is happening in browser only. Or Can we record video on a headless browser ?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: I have added a way to record in my answer... See edit

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't recommend to show the test on the server...

What I have done in the past is to run it locally for a demonstration.

To do that you just run your code via `pytest` locally and put the `chrome_options` that makes it headless in a comment.

for example:

```
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
```

Or if you are using `Xvfb` just comment it out!

```
# vdisplay = Xvfb()
# vdisplay.start()
```

**EDIT**

If you want to record the tests you will need to use `Xvfb`.

To record just use 
The [x-recorder](https://github.com/lightsofapollo/x-recorder):

The x-recorder is easy to use see the [readme](https://github.com/lightsofapollo/x-recorder/blob/master/README.md)

Hope this helps you!